# Проблема с устройством Bluetooth на пк

Tags: сеть, bluetooth

Имеется геймпад (полностью рабочий).После неудачного удаления его из списка подключенных устройств он больше не обнаруживается при поиске, [image: введите сюда описание изображения]и он всегда висит в "других устройствах" и с ним нельзя ничего сделать кроме как удалить (удалить тоже не получается даже через диспетчер устройств,после перезагрузки пк он опять возрашается)